# C++11 Shared Ptr, share the same reference counter

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, reference-counting

Is it possible to have 2 different objects that share same reference counter?

Says I have

```
shared_ptr<Foo> myFoo;
shared_ptr<Bar> myBar;
```

I want both objects alive until there is one reference to Foo or to Bar (so maybe no one is referencing Bar, but since Foo is referenced both will not be deleted).

Comment: alternatively, I need to know how to reinterpret cast shared_ptr<Foo> to shared_ptr<Bar>

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this?

Comment: Here's a C++ protip: if you think you need to cast but can't figure out how, you don't need to cast.

Comment: If no one is referencing `Bar`, why keep it around?

Comment: the point is that I already cast pointers, so I figured how to cast pointers. (i'm using hash map to keep type safety). The problem is now switching to managed pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK perfect I found the answer:
http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/25/shared-ptr-aliasing-constructor/

The aliasing constructor! (code taken from the link)

```
struct data {...};

struct object
{
  data data_;
};

void f ()
{
  shared_ptr<object> o (new object); // use_count == 1
  shared_ptr<data> d (o, &o->data_); // use_count == 2

  o.reset (); // use_count == 1

  // When d goes out of scope, object is deleted.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Put them in a struct and have the `shared_ptr` own that struct.

```
struct FooBar {
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
};
shared_ptr<FooBar> myFooBar;
```

Comment: And from that you can use the shared_ptr [ctor 8 from outer space](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) to get shared_ptrs to the individual parts, if it is really necessary.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "ctor 8 from outer space"  Brilliant!